# android table layout rowspan

Tags: android, tablelayout, html-table

I want to build the following layout but it is not working.

[alt text http://toms-toy.de/rowspan.gif](http://toms-toy.de/rowspan.gif)

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"...>
  <ImageView ...></ImageView>
        <TableLayout ...>
                        <TableRow..>
                              <ImageView ...></ImageView>
                              <ImageView ...></ImageView>
                              <ImageView ...></ImageView>
                        </TableRow>
                         <TableRow..>
                              <ImageView ...></ImageView>
                              <ImageView ...></ImageView>
                              <ImageView ...></ImageView>
                        </TableRow>
       </TableLayout>
  <ImageView ...></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I found [this really nice tutorial on tableLayout](http://coderzheaven.com/index.php/2011/03/android-tablelayout/).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I put this together really fast, try this:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="50dip" android:layout_height="100dip" android:background="#cc0000"/>
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="50dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:background="#aaaa00"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="50dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:background="#00aa00"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="50dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:background="#aaaa00"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="50dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:background="#00aa00"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="50dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:background="#aaaa00"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="50dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:background="#00aa00"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="50dip" android:layout_height="100dip" android:background="#cc0000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ideally the width of the imageviews should be wrap_content, and the width of the tablelayout, 0dip. Then add a layout_weight of 1.0 to the tablelayout.

Comment: Just wanted to thank Jeffrey for this, I was pulling my hair out trying to figure this out and just so everyone knows, the orientation="horizontal" is very important! Best, Mike

Answer (score 7):

try out this:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="1-2, 1;\t" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <TableLayout>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="1, 2;\t" android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="2, 2;\t" android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The output of the below code

[image: enter ima,ge description here]

By Default the android doesn't have any attribute called rowspan but the below code works fine and created the row span.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"

            />
        <Button android:text="Click me"
            android:textSize="30dp"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            />
           <Button android:text="Click"
            android:textSize="30dp"
               android:layout_column="2"/>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            />
        <Button android:text="Click me"
            android:textSize="30dp"/>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_span="2">
            <TableRow>
                <Button android:text="1"/>
                <Button android:text="2"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <Button android:text="3"/>
                <Button android:text="4"/>
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter"
            android:background="#ff0099"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```