# How to I make TableView Cells spanning over multiple rows?

Tags: android, layout, tableview

is there a way to create a tableview in which a
cell may span over more than one row. As the two "X" here?

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 1 X 1 2
1 2 X 4 5
```

Comment: What's up with all the duplicate questions lately?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189986/android-table-layout-rowspan

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is only duplicate on first glimpse.

How should the above table be splitted into nested
tables without misaligning columns? You would have to put the first row into a separate table which means that the columns to not say aligned. Imagine this:

```
1 222 3 4 5
2 1 X 1 2
1 2 X 4 5
```

You wont get both "4" cells aligned.