# Layout problem with Android: rotated TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm building an Android app on which I have to represent data in a Table-like format.
So I'm using TableLayout. The problem is that I have to draw a rotated string like in the following raw example:

[image]

How can I create my layout to be able to show the '2011' rotated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extend the [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) class and override the `onDraw` method.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     canvas.save();
     canvas.rotate(90, xPivot, yPivot);
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     canvas.restore();

}
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you; but ... if i rotate the TextView in a TableRow cell i also need to make a sort of ROWSPAN because the 2011 needs to use 3 rows ... how can i do that?

Comment: Rowspan is not possible AFAIK. You will have to put that rotated view and the views next to it inside a RelativeLayout or other view group. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189986/android-table-layout-rowspan

Comment: Thank you very much, your link will surely help me !

Comment: Did this work for anyone, I can't get it to work - I'm using an XML file for the view. Thanks, M

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but maybe someone else could need this.

You can do this by using xml-layouts, too. As you want a "table-like" format, I recommend you to use a GridLayout for your purposes.

Here you can define your TextViews and assign them to the row and column you want. Use the parameters `android:layout_column="..."` and `android:layout_row="..."` to tell the TextView in which column and row it should appear.

As of API11 you can use the xml-attribute called `android:rotation="..."` for rotating your TextView. The attribute uses a float-value which represents the angle for rotating your TextView.

The if you are developing for API14 and above you can use the `android:layout_rowspan="..."` attribute for generating the rowspan in the GridLayout

For example a little code:

```html
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- column 0 start -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="ABC" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:rotation="-90.0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="2011" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:text="DEF" />
    <!-- column 0 end -->
    
    <!-- column 1 start -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="XXXXX" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="XXXXX" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:text="XXXXX" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:text="XXXXX" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:text="XXXXX" />
    <!-- column 1 end -->
</GridLayout>
```

This is a small screenshot how the layout looks like
[image: screenshot of the given layout example]