# Rotating Text in Android

Tags: android, textview

I am creating an Android application. The design calls for rotated text as seen for the "Physical Exam" label in the image below. I have used "android:rotation='270'" but the layout doesn't work out right.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the "Physical Exam" label to look like the image?

[image: Physical Exam Label]

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636474/layout-problem-with-android-rotated-textview

Answer (score 1):

If you are drawing to a canvas, you can use the `translate()` method to temporarily rotate the canvas, write to it, then translate it back.

More info at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate(float,%20float)

Here is a good example:
http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2008/11/android-graphics-example/

Edit:
Since you are handling this directly in the layout, here is a good solution from another Stackoverflow post:
[Vertical (rotated) label in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android)

Comment: I have it in the View as a TextView.

Comment: @Dan, hopefully my edited response will help a little better.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solution:

**1. Using rotate in Animation:**
[TextView Rotate Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888780/is-it-possible-to-write-vertically-in-a-textview-in-android)

**2. Extend TextView**
[Custom TextView to rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android)