# How to rotate text and align properly in android?

Tags: android

I try to rotate text in android. Text rotate properly, but not align properly.
Some words are visible some not. Can you tell how to fixed these problem.

Comment: follow the following link [Rotatinf Text][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887200/rotating-text-in-android

Comment: Yes you tried to rotate then post the code here.