# How to apply row span in tablelayout?

Tags: java, android, row, html, tablelayout

How to apply row_span to TableLayout?

I want to make something similar to this image, but i don't know how to do it.

[image: table image]

What is the correct way to make something like this?

Comment: seems like a possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189986/android-table-layout-rowspan

Comment: Is not duplicated. That's not the answer to the question I asked.

Comment: did you got any solution for this

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`TableLayout` does not support row spans, only column spans. `GridLayout` supports both row and column spans:

[image: GridLayout sample]

(picture from http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html)

Answer (score 8):

Little cheating (maybe quite complex to code and only valid for a simple design):

Make a `TableLayout`. Put another `TableLayout` inside the first column and a view that you want to have the rowspan in the second column. This inner `TableLayout` can have as many `TableRows` as you whish the other view to span.

Here's the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.5">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Row 1"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Row 2"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Row 3"/>

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:text="Second column, rowspan 3"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So, tu sum up:

TableLayout: first column (TableLayout with as many TableRows as we want), second column (element that will take up all those rows' space).

[image]

Comment: i missed something ? how u make two rows  == two columns ? u should put two table layouts in one row to achieve two columns then in nested tablelayout put rows &  in second tablelayout one row or any other content. then in second row set span=2

Comment: I'm sorry. it's a mistake. I meant two columns, not two rows. The thing is, the first column contains a TableLayout with as many rows as you want to span and the second column contains only one view. I'll edit.

Comment: Using this for a row list item just what I needed ha