# How to implement this kind of layout

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the [design effect](http://imgbin.org/images/15579.png).

[image]

I tried to use the `LinearLayout` to implement it like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:text="Type"
            android:background="@drawable/poi_nearby_cell"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:text="Type1"
                android:background="@drawable/poi_nearby_cell"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="Type2"
                android:background="@drawable/poi_nearby_cell"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:text="Type3"
                android:background="@drawable/poi_nearby_cell"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="Type4"
                android:background="@drawable/poi_nearby_cell"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the `poi_nearby_cell`:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent">
    </solid>

    <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="#A0A0A0">
    </stroke>

</shape>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cb3J.png) is what I got now.

[image]

However I meet many problems:

1 I use the `drawable/poi_nearby_cell` to create the border for the textview.

However I have also to implement the cell press effect like the "Type1" in the design effect picture. Generally I set axml drawable resource as the background like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="#ffebf6ff"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="#fffefefe"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

However in my case, I cannot set a view with two background at the same time. Any alternative?

2 As you can see, the border have different width value. Normally I want the border to be `1dp` however, in my example, the border between two cell maybe `2dp`.

I have no idea to continue. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have tried the table layout, but it does not support the row-span.

Comment: Use a table inside a table: outer table with 2 colums and one row. Inside 2 columns and 3 rows for the right panel.

Comment: Then how about the cell border and cell-press style?

Comment: @hguser it supports [spans](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html)!

Comment: @rekire:http://stackoverflow.com/a/16126378/306719. Check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this
**layout_bg.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#333333" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</shape>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
        android:padding="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Type"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/white">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Type1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/white">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Type2"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/white">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Type3"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/white">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Type4"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```