# Set rowSpan programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an `ImageView` in my `TableRow` that needs to have a rowSpan. However, I only found tutorials to do this with XML.

Like this one here:

[android table layout rowspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189986/android-table-layout-rowspan)

Is it even possible to do rowspan with `TableLayout` or do I have to use `GridLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change height and width etc of you ImageView by using the ImageView.setLayoutParams(LayoutParams) method.